# Is there anyway to set the VC++ Directories at project level in VS2008 as in VS2010?

Tags: visual-c++

In VS2010 the VC++ Directories editing in Tools > Options has been deprecated. VC++ Directories are now available as a user property sheet， which is very convenient to keep the include/lib directories depending on different projects. Is there any way to do the similar thing in VS2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around, I figured out a way to partially do it: still with the property sheet.
we can create a new property sheet and set following items:

`C/C++->additional include directories`

`linker->additional lib directories`

`linker->additional dependencies`

...

This will do most of the VC++ directories.
However, the executable directories is still missing. There are two parts need to be done.

1. the executable path while building, this can be set via add user macros:PATH (for example: `c:\sss;%PATH%`), then check the box on the bottom to expose this variable to the building environment.
2. However, while debugging the DLL directories may still missing. We can then set this in project properties->debugging->environment:`PATH=%DLLPATH%;%PATH%` which will allow the debugger add the DLLPATH to the environment PATH.