# CMake Error Could NOT find Boost (using Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

In my `CMakeLists.txt` file, I have this:

```
# Locate Boost date_time library
set(PROGRAM_FILES "Program Files")
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR C:/${PROGRAM_FILES})
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.58 REQUIRED COMPONENTS date_time)
```

I have my boost directory located at `C:\Program Files\boost` and in that directory there is a `date_time` directory and a `date_time.hpp` header file.

My error:

```
Error       
CMake Error at 
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):

  Could NOT find Boost (missing: date_time) (found suitable version "1.72.0",
  minimum required is "1.58")   C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake    137
```

Comment: The error is about not finding the Boost. Do you have the Boost installed? If so, where have you installed it?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have Visual Studio. how can i find out?

Comment: Visual Studio will not tell you anything about whether Boost is installed on your system. You need to install it yourself. I suggest you read through [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) page, which explains how to get started with Boost (including unzipping and building Boost).

Comment: @squareskittles but when you download visual studio it gives you the option for additional packages. I think i clicked the boost option.

Comment: Did you install it with the Nuget package manager within Visual Studio?

Comment: @squareskittles i thought so yes

Comment: It will be really hard to help with so little information. I think I can find another question that had the same problem but with so little knowledge about your setup it may not be accurate

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54581717/2104697